# How to do visible data binding in Knockout for table?

Tags: knockout.js, binding

I have a table listing by foreach loop. I want to have one more column which contains `Edit`, `Validate`, and `Cancel`.

When the user clicks on `Edit`, the input tag should be displayed and allow user to enter a value and validate or cancel. Then, the input tag should be hidden.

Here is my fidder: http://jsfiddle.net/v9BNr/14/

```
<table>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: mapDictionaryToArray(contents())">
      <tr>
         <td> <span id="textKey" data-bind="text: $data.key"></span>
         </td>
         <td> 
            <input data-bind="value:$data.value"  />
            <label data-bind="text:$data.value" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <a href="#" 
               data-bind="">
            Edit</a> 
            <a href="#" 
               data-bind="">
            Apply</a>
            <a href="#" 
               data-bind="">
            Cancel</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Knockout you can just use the `visible:` binding and set it to an expression that returns a `boolean`,

```
<td> 
  <input data-bind="value:$data.value,visible:$data.isEditing" />
  <label data-bind="text:$data.value" />
</td>
```

You can add a property to your view model that defines the expression and use as such. I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9BNr/15/) with a rough implementation.

Comment: I though that the data-bind of visible is at the input tags to set the visibilities, can I also set at those a links?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/v9BNr/16 I have fixed but it still doesnt work for the editing, could you please have a look at my fidde ? the problem as far as I know because I do have a foreach loop at the top. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question as noted by @rae1 is quite ambiguous, however, taking it that your requirements are to edit a field in the table which is generated by iterating through an array this fiddle should solve your question [Editing A Row and validating it - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lordbalmung/r327k/2/)

Let me explain,

Again, as @rae1 stated using the `visible` toggle is your best choice, however there are many ways to do it. The code below (and in the fiddle) is the simplest way simply fixing it onto an observable. The links `edit` and `validate` simply toggle the value of the observable `editMode` which due to knockout subscriptions affects the control which would be visible to the user

Blockquote

**View Model**

```
var viewModel = {
    data: []
};

function element(datum) {
    var moi = this;
    moi.editMode = ko.observable(false);
    moi.value = ko.observable(datum);
    moi.edit = function (koObj, jqObj) {
        moi.editMode(true);
    };
    moi.validate = function (koObj, jqObj) {
        moi.editMode(false);
    };
}

viewModel.data[viewModel.data.length] = new element('Hi');
viewModel.data[viewModel.data.length] = new element('I');
viewModel.data[viewModel.data.length] = new element('like');
viewModel.data[viewModel.data.length] = new element('to');
viewModel.data[viewModel.data.length] = new element('smile');

$(document).ready(function (event) {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

**View**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:data">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-bind="click:edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#" data-bind="click:validate">validate</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value:value, visible:editMode()" />
                <span data-bind="text:value, visible:!editMode()"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

However, this is only useful when the structure of your grid or table is static and only the number of rows that is number of array items vary. If you had a grid whose width or the number of columns was also dynamic then you will have to use knockoutjs' `virtual elements`

Comment: Thanks for your guide, however, when I tried with my example when I did the parsing the dictionary the data display incorrectly as following : http://jsfiddle.net/v9BNr/17/

Comment: Could you please have a look at this topic, thanks : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180199/modify-validate-observable-of-editable-table-in-knockoutjs

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<td style="width:50px;"> <span data-bind="text: first, visible:!isEdit()"></span><input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="textInput: first, visible: isEdit()" style="width:95%" /></td>
```

Demo in action: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/5pznw6re/)

I have also updated your fiddle here: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/v9BNr/25/)