# Modify Validate Observable of editable table in KnockoutJS

Tags: c#, html, json, knockout.js

I'm actually doing my project the editable grid, my data comes from the JSON and parsed to dictionary to have key and value and display on the table.

I have one more column to have 3 links, Modify, Validate and Cancel.

However, the value from input tag, after editing by user, cannot be updated to the label tag.

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.testParams(parameters())">
                            <tr class="data-hover">
                                <td>
                                    <strong>
                                        <span id="key_params" data-bind="text:$data.key" />
                                    </strong>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @*display label and input for dictionary<value>*@

                                    <input type="text" class="edit" data-bind="value:value,visible:$root.isItemEditing($data)" />
                                    <label class="read" data-bind="text:value,visible:!$root.isItemEditing($data)" />        

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" class="action" data-bind="click: $root.editData.bind($root),visible:!$root.isItemEditing($data)">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>&nbsp;Modify
                                    </a>

                                    <a  class="action" href="#" data-bind="click: $root.applyData.bind($root),visible:$root.isItemEditing($data)">

                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>&nbsp;Validate
                                    </a>

                                    <a class="action" href="#" data-bind="click: $root.cancelData.bind($root),visible:$root.isItemEditing($data)">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>&nbsp;Cancel
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                   </table>
```

config.js

```
function ConfigurationViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.testParams = mapDictionaryToArray;
    self.value = ko.observable();

    self.parameters = ko.observableArray();
    self.editingItem = ko.observable();
    self.isItemEditing = function (datum) {
        return datum == self.editingItem();
    };

    self.editData = function (datu) {
        if (self.editingItem() == null) {
            self.editingItem(datu);
        }
    };

    self.applyData = function () {

        self.editingItem(null);
    };


    self.cancelData = function () {
        self.editingItem(null);
    };
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new RateScreenerConfigurationViewModel());
});
```

> ```
> bus.js
> var mapDictionaryToArray =
>
>     function (dictionary) {
>         var result = [];
>         dictionary = JSON.parse(dictionary);
>         for (var key in dictionary) {
>             if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
>                 result.push({
>                     key: key,
>                     value: dictionary[key]
>                 });
>             }
>         }
>         return result;
>
>     };
> ```

Comment: Could you please state the actual question?  And let us know what error you're getting or what isn't working.

Comment: @PatrickSteele : My question as stated above is the input tag which is visible when it is in the Edit of visible binding, then I enter a new value to the input tag, click Validate, but the label tag doesnt get the update of new value which is entered in the input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem was value needed to be an observable so that when it was modified in the textbox, the label is also updated.

The next is isEditing needed to be an observable so that it can be switched from edit mode to display mode.

```
result.push({
             key: key,
             value: ko.observable(dictionary[key]),
             isEditing: ko.observable(false)
           });

<input data-bind="value:value,visible:isEditing()"  />
<label data-bind="text:value,visible:!isEditing()" />
```

The last problem was the click functions were invalid and not even added to the model.

```
edit: function (item) {
    item.isEditing(true);
},
cancel: function (item) {
    item.isEditing(false);
}

<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.edit">Edit</a> 
<a href="#" data-bind="">Apply</a>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.cancel">Cancel</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wdj6X/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use that function because my data which i dont have the control on, is JSON format and I'd like to transfer it into Dictionary key and value. Can I ask you that why you return new Object View Model

Comment: @TrangZinita I'm newing it because I've create a new function for the objects in the array. There are other ways to do it but it offers more flexibility if I want to add more functionality to the object. The name is poor as I didn't know what was in it. If you have a look at step 2 on here it does the same thing: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving step 2.

Comment: In order for the label to be updated based on the text input, it needs to be an observerable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it also worked for me if I have the files like in your Fidder, but when I split them into 3 files, which is biz.js, config.js and the cshtml file, when I set the visible for data-bind, the foreach just loops once, could you please have a look at this notepad : http://notepad.cc/share/62xVGi2Yob

Comment: You are missing the parameters observer able from the viewModel

Comment: Yeh, I have added  parameters: ko.observable(parameters); into the Model the data can be looped normally, just when I set the visibility of the tag in data-bind, I think I should make the observable for isEditing too ? Thanks

Comment: Visibility of what tag?

Comment: Visibilities of input and label tags, the problem of for each loop occurs when I set the visible for data-bind